# Reaper : midi configuration problem

Tags: midi, reaper

I have a computer with a keyboard synthesizer. I created 2 MIDI tracks. On each of them I added a virtual instrument, and I assigned a channel number to each of them (track one, channel 1 of my device, track two, channel 2 ...).

My problem is: when I select (I click on) Track 1 and I played on the synth, all is ok. when I select track 2 and I played on the synth, I hear the track 1 (and not the 2).

In other words, I have to manually change the channel from the synthesizer (set it to 2) to hear the track 2.

The twelve o'clock output Seems To be configured Correctly ...

In fact, I could simplify my question, I realized that the 'problem' is the same with the virtual keyboard: whatever the chosen track the midi channel must be changed manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your device will not change output channel just because you select another track in Reaper.

Some alternative options to consider:

1. Set up the Reaper tracks to track 1/channel 1 and track 2/channel 2. Then only change channel on your device (depending on model you may be able to store that with a preset).
2. Set up the device or reaper to omni/all inputs or set the Reaper tracks to the same channels and then use mute/solo buttons.